# Opportunity Required Field Missing in soap

Tags: apex, soap-api, webservices, soap

while insert the opportunity it throws an error requried field is missing but i asign the requried fields are **Name,StageName**
the field my code is

i declare like this

```
global class OpportunityWrapper {
    webservice String oName;
    webservice String ocDate;
    webservice String oStage;
}

// some other code which consit of account,contact insert code

List<Opportunity> lstopp = new List<Opportunity>();

{
    OpportunityWrapper o1 = new OpportunityWrapper();  
    Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
    o.Name = o1.oName;
    o.CloseDate = system.today();
    o.StageName = o1.oStage;
    lstopp.add(o);
}
insert lstopp;
```

May i know what modifications i have to do.

Comment: Does the error say *which* Required Field is missing?

Comment: Name,StageName Missing

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are setting the `Name` and `StageName` fields to blank values.

```
OpportunityWrapper o1 = new OpportunityWrapper(); //<--- CREATING A NEW RECORD; it's blank
Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
o.Name = o1.oName;   // <----- Setting the NAME to o1's Name which has never been set
o.CloseDate = system.today();
o.StageName = o1.oStage; // <----- Setting the StageName to o1's Stage which also has never been set
lstopp.add(o);
```

Try adding some debug/validation to those fields to see what they are really set to:

```
OpportunityWrapper o1 = new OpportunityWrapper(); 
Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
o.Name = o1.oName;   
o.CloseDate = system.today();
o.StageName = o1.oStage; 

system.debug('o.Name = '+o.Name);
system.debug('o.StageName = '+o.StageName);

lstopp.add(o);
```

If this class was used on a Visualforce page, you could add a Page Message displaying the error:

```
OpportunityWrapper o1 = new OpportunityWrapper(); 
Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
o.Name = o1.oName;   
o.CloseDate = system.today();
o.StageName = o1.oStage; 

system.debug('o.Name = '+o.Name);
system.debug('o.StageName = '+o.StageName);

if(string.isBlank(o.Name)){
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'o.Name is Blank.  BAD_o.Name = "'+o.Name+'"'));
    return null;  // escape the method the INSERT never happens because the data is INVALID
} else if(string.isBlank(o.StageName)){
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'o.StageNameis Blank.  BAD_o.StageName= "'+o.Name+'"'));
    return null;  // escape the method the INSERT never happens because the data is INVALID
}
lstopp.add(o);
```